# Anchor tag with two events firing, fade-out not engaging on exit

Tags: jquery, html, alert

I am trying to make my logout button fire two actions. The first is to simply log out of the system, then I want it to use my jQuery to fire the alert and I want it to stay for 3 seconds and then fade. It is currently working, but fades out very quickly. I have to add the "#" to the href= bit and it cancels out the action that is already logging the user out of the system. I am working in a Silverstripe SS template file for reference. Is there a way to add the "#" to the "{Link}logout" without breaking it? This is on a test server so no fiddle, sorry...

The alert works fine when i add it to the anchor like so, but then does not logout:

```
href="# {$Link}logout"
```

Current HTML that does not fade:

```
<a href="{$Link}logout" id="show-my-alert" class="btn btn-default btn-menu-donate-offcanvas btn-side">
<i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i><br><span class="donate-text"> SIGN OUT</a>

<div id="my-alert" class="alert alert-warning hidden" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">    
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button> 
<strong>Warning!</strong> You are now logged out of the system.
```

jQuery

```
<script>

$("#show-my-alert, .close").click(function() {
$("#my-alert").toggleClass("hidden").fadeIn(3000);
$("#my-alert").fadeOut(3000);
});

</script>
```

THE FINAL SCRIPT IN USE AS OF NOW:

```
$(function () {
$("#show-my-alert, .close").click(function(e) {
var isClosing = $("#my-alert").data("isClosing");
if (isClosing === undefined || isClosing != true) {
  $("#my-alert").toggleClass("hidden").fadeOut(3000, function() {

    $("#my-alert").data("isClosing", true);
  });
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent logout during fading
} else {
  // this time logout
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: You say your code is working ok but the '.fadeOut(3000); is happening faster than 3 seconds. Could you estimate that time better than the term 'very quickly'. Is is out in the blink of an eye or longer? Any way to measure the fadeout time? It could give clues to the problem.

Comment: It only works when I have the # in front of the {$Link}logout, otherwise it does not fade. Without the #, It shows the message maybe for a tenth of a second before its gone. It actually does logout either way...correction from before...

Comment: I have no way to test this but should not .fadeIn and .fadeOut have symmetry? It would become .toggleClass("visible").fadeOut(3000);

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense now that i see it written out, I am still new to programming so thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the product you are using, but in simple jQuery I can do (I hope this could help you):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#show-my-alert, .close").click(function(e) {
    var isClosing = $("#my-alert").data('isClosing');
    if (isClosing === undefined || isClosing != true) {
      $("#my-alert").toggleClass("hidden").fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $("#my-alert").fadeIn(3000, function() {
          document.getElementById("show-my-alert").click();
        });
        $("#my-alert").data('isClosing', true);
      });
      e.preventDefault();  // prevent logout during fading
    } else {
      // this time logout
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<a href="{$Link}logout" id="show-my-alert" class="btn btn-default btn-menu-donate-offcanvas btn-side">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i><br><span class="donate-text"> SIGN OUT</a>

<div id="my-alert" class="alert alert-warning hidden" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> You are now logged out of the system.
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, I had to get rid of the fade in bit for it to work properly. I will update my question with the working bit. Thank you! This will help when writing some other functions that are similar.

Comment: @UX.DevDude So, could you accept and upvote my answer?

Comment: @UX.DevDude Thanks so much